# $P(X>n\delta)\leq c{\beta}^n$ implies $E(X^\alpha)<\infty$ for $\alpha>0.$

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the next:

Suppose $X\geq 0$ is a random variable. Also there is $\delta>0$ and $0<\beta<1$ such that $P(X>n\delta)\leq c{\beta}^n,$ where $c$ is a constant. Then $E(X^{\alpha})<\infty$ for $\alpha>0.$

I'm stuck proving this. I was using the formula of expected value of $X:$

$$E(X^\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\alpha x^{\alpha-1}P(X>x)dx$$ because $\alpha>0$ and trying to split such expectation in the sets where $\{X\leq n\delta\}$ and $\{X> n\delta\}$ but I am not sure how to use them; the hypotesis gives us the convergence $P(\{X> n\delta\})\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty,$ so I suppose such convergence must be used to bound the expectation but I do not find the correc way to do this.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may suppose $\alpha >1$. Split the integral into integrals over the intervals $(n\delta,(n+1)\delta)$. $\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta} \alpha x^{\alpha -1} P(X>x)dx \leq \int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta} \alpha x^{\alpha -1} dx P(X>n\delta)$. So all that you need now is to show that $\sum \beta^{n} [(n+1)^\alpha-n^{\alpha}] <\infty$. But this is an easy consequence of MVT and ratio test.

[ $(n+1)^\alpha-n^{\alpha} =\alpha t^{\alpha -1} \leq \alpha (n+1)^{\alpha -1}$ where $n<t<n+1$].

Comment: Thanks to answer. Every step is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I will only consider $\alpha\geq1$.
$$E(X^\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \alpha x^{\alpha-1}P(X>x)\,dx=\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{n\delta}^{(n+1)\delta}x^{\alpha-1}P(X>x)\,dx\leq\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)^{\alpha-1}\delta^\alpha c\beta^n<\infty.$$

Here the series is convergent since for large $n$ we have $n^{\alpha-1}<\gamma^n$ where $1<\gamma<\frac{1}{\beta}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help.